# Mollom captcha widget not showing up on a custom form

Tags: 7, forms, advertising

D7 + Mollom. I want my users to fill in captcha on a custom form every time they click a link like `/file/123/download` on my site. I'm trying to bend Mollom captcha to my needs but haven't had any success with it yet. Mollom public and private keys say they have been verified by Mollom server and are working all right even though my site is still at localhost. I also implemented [hook_mollom_form_list()](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_mollom_form_list/7) and [hook_mollom_form_info($form_id)](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_mollom_form_info/7) for my custom form and have set the form to be protected by Mollom in its settings. Yet I see no Mollom widget on my form. Here is my code:

```php
//registering custom form path with hook_menu()
function MYMODULE_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['file/%/download'] = array(
      'page callback' => '_MYMODULE_custom_form',
      'title' => 'My custom form',
      'page arguments' => array(1),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

//getting custom form
function _MYMODULE_custom_form($fid)
{
    return drupal_get_form('_my_custom_form');
}

//creating a form with Drupal Form API (here is a form with a submit button)
function _my_custom_form()
{
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Test form submit button'),
        );

    return $form;
}

//implementing hook_mollom_form_list
function MYMODULE_mollom_form_list() {
   $forms['_my_custom_form'] = array(
     'title' => t('My custom form'),
   );
   return $forms;
}

//implementing hook_mollom_form_info()
function MYMODULE_mollom_form_info($form_id) {
   switch ($form_id) {
     case '_my_custom_form':
       $form_info = array(
                'mode' => MOLLOM_MODE_CAPTCHA,
                'elements' => array(),
                'mapping' => array(),
            );
       return $form_info;
       break;
   }
}
```

When I click links like `http://example.com/file/123/download` I see a form title "My custom form" and a submit button "Test form submit button" but no Mollom widget. Obviously I'm missing something but can't understand what exactly.

Comment: As side note, you can avoid using `_MYMODULE_custom_form()`; use `'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form'`, and `'page arguments' => array('_my_custom_form', 1)`.